# Spark read from Entire Schema Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, schema

I want to create a Spark object that can read an entire schema instead of just one table from inside that schema. This is because I want to execute a particular query that joins multiple tables (I do not want to read from each table separately and manually recreate the query using Spark as the query is long and complicated). I was hoping it would work something like this:

```
val Schema_DF = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc://example.com")
    .option("schema", "SCHEMA_NAME")
    .option("user", "username")
    .option("password", "pass")
    .load()
```

I am able to use a different method to load the query I want as a ResultSet, but this seems long winded as I would then need to convert this to a Dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: your methods loads a single dataframe, so indeed this won't load all tables. Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493740/how-to-fetch-multiple-tables-using-spark-sql ? - I know it's Python, but for Scala it's almost the same way

Comment: also what is the purpose of loading all tables and then doing the join in Spark? Isn't it more efficient to do it directly on the database? OR am I missing something in your workflow?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.

I have already loaded each table individually as a separate Dataframe and done the joins in Spark manually. The purpose of this question is to be able to execute the entire query as it is, and validate whether the manual joins I have done in Spark generate the correct output. 

I have been able to execute the query and store the results as a ResultSet in Scala, but it is difficult to compare a ResultSet to a Dataframe - hence I am trying to connect to the entire Schema as a Dataframe so that my two tables are of the same type. Let me know if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to load whole schemas into spark to do that.

You can query on your DB and get results as a dataframe using the `query` property.

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", jdbcUrl)
.option("query", "select c1, c2 from t1")
.load()
```

Ref : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

**Note:** Spark will push this query to your Database i.e. Your database will process the query and spark will just fetch the results. Just be careful if it's your live prod database :)

Comment: Thank you!! This works well if a smaller query but every time I try it with a larger query I get a error: ```com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=WITH;HAVING INTERSECT MINUS EXCEPT UNION FETCH OVER CONCAT || / - +, DRIVER=3.72.44``` The exact query runs fine on a client but fails when I try to load it through Spark. Any ideas?

Comment: Have upvoted, just don't have much reputation :) I cannot show the query unfortunately as is very long and contains confidential information but its basically just a series of LEFT JOINS, LEFT OUTER JOIN with some WHERE criteria

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the query. Few pointers: (1). try running your query as spark does i.e. `SELECT <columns> FROM (<user_specified_query>) spark_gen_alias`. replace the `<user_specified_query>` with your query and try in Client. (2) check for any escaping or quotes that is breaking the query (3) worst case : Start with smaller queries and keep correcting it in spark and slowly make it complex

Comment: Thanks for your help. (2) is currently what I am doing